# How to translate 城隍庙 into English?

Tags: translation

In Chinese folklores, 城隍 often makes an appearance; the temple a 城隍 is worshipped is called 城隍庙. How do we translate into English?

Comment: I am not sure if you refer to the 城隍庙 in Shanghai city. In Shanghai, besides 'Cheng Huang Temple' provided by Tang Ho, there are a few more versions: Town God's Temple (the one written in dicts usually), the City God Temple, Yu Yuan Temple.

Comment: Also (Cantonese) Shing Wong Temple http://www.ctc.org.hk/en/directcontrol/temple6.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'[城隍](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9F%8E%E9%9A%8D)' is an officer title in the after-world

'城' stand for '城牆'(city wall); '隍' means 'moat'. '城隍爺' means 'officer of city wall and moat'. Therefore, '城隍庙' should be translated as '**Temple of the civic deity**'

But I prefer transliterate '城隍' as'Cheng Huang' and '**城隍庙**' as '**Cheng Huang Temple**'

**Edit:**

> **civic:**
>
> *relating to a city or **town**, especially its administration; municipal*
>
> *synonyms: municipal, city, **town**, urban, metropolitan*

~

> **deity:**
>
> noun: deity; plural noun: deities
>
> a **god** or goddess (in a polytheistic religion)

So, I guess "Town god's Temple" is also a correct translation for '城隍庙'. However, Town god sounded more like a description of 土地公 (local god)

Answer (score 2):

I find for '城隍庙' 'tutelary genie temple'

> tutelary （adj.): 1610s, from Late Latin tutelarius "a guardian," from
>   Latin tutela "protection, watching" (see tutor (n.)).

Answer (score 1):

**ABC**

> town god's temple

**A Chinese-English Dictionary**

> town god's temple

**Oxford**

> town god's temple

**KEY**

> town god's temple

Notice any pattern?

Answer (score 0):

城隍庙 is a specific tourist destination in Shanghai, China.

It is called **Yu Garden**.

Comment: 豫园 and 城隍庙 are two different place, they located in the **Yuyuan** / **Yu Garden** Tourist Mart.

Comment: English Wikipedia page for 上海城隍庙
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_God_Temple_of_Shanghai

Comment: **Yuyuan** or **Yu Garden** is a metro station name and also a Chineseclassical garden. The area you are touring is a business district, actually **Yu Garden** and **Chenghuang Temple** both located in this area.